# Classical Regression Model: Combining linearity and strict exogeneity

Tags: probability, statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I am studying the Classical Regression Model for random samples.

Hence consider the random sample $(y_i,\mathbf{x_i})$

Where:

$$\mathbf{x_i}=\begin{pmatrix}{x_{i1}}\\{x_{i2}}\\.\\.\\{x_{ik}}\end{pmatrix}$$

Define:

**1. Linearity:** $y_i=x_i'\mathbf{\beta} + e_i$, where $\mathbf{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix}{{\beta}_{1}}\\{{\beta}_{2}}\\.\\.\\{\beta}{k}\end{pmatrix}$

**2. Strict Exogeneity:** $E(e_i|x_i')=0$

I already proved, without lots of trouble, that 1 and 2 imply that:

**3.** $E(y_i|x_i')=x_i'\beta$

However know I need to prove that 3 'implies that there exist error terms that satisfy 1 and 2' (where the 'error terms' are the $e_i$). I am not really sure how to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you just define $e_i = y_i - E(y_i|x_i)$?

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks for replying!